# Can i change SQL database from javascript code?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i need to know how to modify a simple data from a sql table from the javascript code. I explain better with a concrete example:
I have a database (named rubik on the image), with a table (cube_setting), which has a simple column (s) that contains an integer. let's imagine we call this column "i" which initially corresponds to 0 (i = 0). I want through a javascript function to be able to increase i by 1 (i ++), for example with an 'onclick' function on a button. It's possible? I attach a photo of the reference database. Thank you !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TkbJ.png)

Comment: You could send an AJAX request

Comment: So what should i do with ajax? I haven't studied it yet, is it possible with a simple copy-paste without understanding the code at the moment?

Comment: Not easily no. But basically it's a way of making a HTTP request to your server in the background, from JavaScript, without reloading the page (like it would if you submitted a form or clicked a link). The response to that request is then sent back into a variable in your Javascript, instead of automatically updating the entire page. If you send the AJAX request to the URL of a server-side script, such as a PHP script, it can then update the database for you, based on the values you send in the request.

Comment: See https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: ^^^ assuming you want to use jQuery to make the request of course. There's also the fetch() API which doesn't depend on any external library, or there are other competing libraries such as Axios. I'm just mentioning that so that you don't assume jQuery's AJAX function is your only option.

Comment: Understanding AJAX isn't hard, but it will take a moment. It's worth the time. Slapping random code into your app is never a good idea.

Comment: Just in case it is not obvious.  javascript is running on the client's device in his browser.  While the sql database is on your server.  The interaction from the browser to the server is either by refreshing that page, going to a different page or by doing an ajax call that executes a file at the server and returns a response.